# Check if something is overlapping my window?

Tags: wpf, overlap, intptr

How do I check if something is overlapping my Window?

I found this WinForms code which should do the trick:

```
public static bool IsOverlapped(IWin32Window window)
{
    if (window == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("window");
    if (window.Handle == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Window does not yet exist");
    if (!IsWindowVisible(window.Handle))
        return false;

    IntPtr hWnd = window.Handle;
    HashSet<IntPtr> visited = new HashSet<IntPtr> { hWnd };

    // The set is used to make calling GetWindow in a loop stable by checking if we have already
    //  visited the window returned by GetWindow. This avoids the possibility of an infinate loop.

    RECT thisRect;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, out thisRect);

    while ((hWnd = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_HWNDPREV)) != IntPtr.Zero && !visited.Contains(hWnd))
    {
        visited.Add(hWnd);
        RECT testRect, intersection;
        if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd) && GetWindowRect(hWnd, out testRect) && IntersectRect(out intersection, ref thisRect, ref testRect))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int uCmd);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, [Out] out RECT lpRect);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool IntersectRect([Out] out RECT lprcDst, [In] ref RECT lprcSrc1, [In] ref RECT lprcSrc2);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

private const int GW_HWNDPREV = 3;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct RECT
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
}
```

But I am not sure how to make it work on WPF, can someone help me out?
I tried a lot of things already..

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the handle for a given WPF window you can use the `System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper` class.  An update to the `IsOverlapped` would allow you to interact with the WinForms code:

```
public static bool IsOverlapped(Window window)
{
    if (window == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("window");

    var hWnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
    if (hWnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Window does not yet exist");
    if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
        return false;

    HashSet<IntPtr> visited = new HashSet<IntPtr> { hWnd };

    // The set is used to make calling GetWindow in a loop stable by checking if we have already
    //  visited the window returned by GetWindow. This avoids the possibility of an infinate loop.

    RECT thisRect;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, out thisRect);

    while ((hWnd = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_HWNDPREV)) != IntPtr.Zero && !visited.Contains(hWnd))
    {
        visited.Add(hWnd);
        RECT testRect, intersection;
        if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd) && GetWindowRect(hWnd, out testRect) && IntersectRect(out intersection, ref thisRect, ref testRect))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :D Unfortunately, I tried it out and it thinks it's being overlapped even though it's not. :(

Answer (score 1):

I solved it this way:

```
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    private void TmrCheckTopmost_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!GetForegroundWindow().Equals(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle))
        {
            Topmost = false;
            Topmost = true;
            Focus();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static bool IsOverlappedElement(FrameworkElement element)
{
    var hwndYourWindow = ((HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual(Window.GetWindow(element))).Handle;
    var controlRect = GetAbsolutePlacement(element);
    var overlappingWindows = GetOverlappingWindowsRectangle(WindowsListFactory.Load(), hwndYourWindow, controlRect).ToList();
    return overlappingWindows.Any();
}
```

**GetOverlappingWindowsRectangle methods inputs:**

1. *WindowsListFactory.Load()* returns with all relevant active windows data
   (the following github repository contains this function... [click here](https://github.com/christianrondeau/GoToWindow/blob/e41b822e7254fdc40a40fbbeec251e6ffc1959f8/GoToWindow.Api/WindowsListFactory.cs).)
2. *hwndYourWindow* is your window which contains your UI element.
3. *controlRect* is your element path (to detect overlapping).

The following function will return with (real) windows which is overlapped your visual element (or window).

```
    private IEnumerable<WindowEntry> GetOverlappingWindowsRectangle(IEnumerable<WindowEntry> filteredWindows, IntPtr interrupterHwnd, Rect displayedControl)
    {
        const uint GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;

        var byHandle = filteredWindows.ToDictionary(win => win.HWnd);

        for (IntPtr hWnd = GetTopWindow(IntPtr.Zero); hWnd != IntPtr.Zero; hWnd = GetWindow(hWnd, GW_HWNDNEXT))
        {
            if (interrupterHwnd == hWnd) break;

            if (byHandle.ContainsKey(hWnd) == false) continue;

            var result = GetWindowRect(new HandleRef(this, hWnd), out RECT rect);

            if (result == false) continue;

            byHandle[hWnd].Frame = CreateRectangle(rect);

            if (displayedControl.IntersectsWith(byHandle[hWnd].Frame) == false) continue;

            yield return byHandle[hWnd];
        }
    }

//Helper methods:

    private Rect CreateRectangle(RECT rect)
    {
        var rectangle = new Rect();
        rectangle.X = rect.Left;
        rectangle.Y = rect.Top;
        rectangle.Width = rect.Right - rect.Left + 1;
        rectangle.Height = rect.Bottom - rect.Top + 1;

        return rectangle;
    }

    private Rect GetAbsolutePlacement(FrameworkElement element, bool relativeToScreen = false)
    {
        var absolutePos = element.PointToScreen(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));
        if (relativeToScreen)
        {
            return new Rect(absolutePos.X, absolutePos.Y, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight);
        }
        var posMW = Application.Current.MainWindow.PointToScreen(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));
        absolutePos = new System.Windows.Point(absolutePos.X - posMW.X, absolutePos.Y - posMW.Y);
        return new Rect(absolutePos.X, absolutePos.Y, element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetTopWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("User32")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint wCmd);
```

Comment: I spent two hours now to test out the code you posted here. I had to add the Frame property to WindowEntry and IWindowEntry. Also the method GetAbsolutePlacement worked by passing relativeToScreen = true. It would be nice if we could get all the source code here into a Nuget package (the source code is MIT license). Now, windows overlapping/masking the FrameworkElement seems to work. I see that Width and Height of controlRect sometimes is 0, so I set it to be at least 100 pixels to get a bounding box "near" the element. So your sample code worked, albeit some work needed to get it to function.